# ko.mapping.fromJS and Date objects

Tags: knockout.js

I've asked questions about knockout in the past but haven't had a chance to work on knockout since the last question was addressed. My latest question is specifically about the use of ko.mapping.fromJS where a Date object is involved.

When I use ko.mapping.fromJS to map an object that has a nested Date object that Date object gets translated to...I don't know what it is.

Here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L5sgW/46/

HTML:

```
<p> <span>Name:</span>
 <span data-bind="text: IntroData.Name"></span>

    <button id="update" data-bind="click: Update">Update!</button>
</p>
```

Javascipt:

```
var ViewModel = function (data) {
    var me = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, me);

    me.Update = function () {
        alert(stuff2.IntroData.TestDate.toString('yyyy-MM-dd'));
        ko.mapping.fromJS(stuff2, {}, me);
        alert(me.IntroData.TestDate.toString('yyyy-MM-dd'));
    };

    return me;
};

var stuff = {
    IntroData: {
        Name: 'Test'
    }
};

var stuff2 = {
    IntroData: {
        TestDate: new Date('2013-09-01'),
        Name: 'Test2'
    }
};

window.viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(new ViewModel(stuff));
ko.applyBindings(window.viewModel);
```

When you click the "Update!" button "Stuff2.IntroData.TestDate" is displayed in the alert. Then the mapping occurs. When the alert for "me.IntroData.TestDate" happens it results in: "function d(){if(0

Why doesn't the date value get preserved? How do I preserve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

: )

Remember that you need the parentheses to get the property of TestDate -

http://jsfiddle.net/L5sgW/47/

```
alert(me.IntroData.TestDate().toString('yyyy-MM-dd'));
```

That was the only line I changed.

Comment: LOL I can't believe I forgot about that. Thanks for the kick in the head and the very quick response

Comment: For you others that encounter this problem, remember that the mapping is turning all properties, including the date, into observables. That's we we need to use parenthesizes to get our values.